# """input().split() in loop""" issues in Pycharm

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu, terminal, pycharm

```
n, m, k, r = tuple([int(i) for i in input().split()])

roads = []

for road in range(m):
    t = tuple(list(map(int, input().split())))
    roads.append(t)

print(roads)
```

My input is:

```
6 6 2 6
0 1
1 2
2 3
3 4
4 1
3 5
```

When I run the above code with the above input, my program works ideally on my Ubuntu terminal and output is this:

```
[(0, 1), (1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4), (4, 1), (3, 5)]
```

But when I run the same code with the same input on my Pycharm, it works without an error but output is unlogical:

```
[(), (0, 1), (), (1, 2), (), (2, 3)]
```

It also works ideally when I do debug on my Ubuntu Pycharm environement. But when I run the codem it outputs unlogical output.

Moreover, When I add additional two print()-s like this:

```
n, m, k, r = tuple([int(i) for i in input().split()])

print()

roads = []

for road in range(m):
    t = tuple(list(map(int, input().split())))
    print()
    roads.append(t)


print(roads)
```

In this case every thing is fine.

Why? What is the matter?

Comment: It's easy to see *what* is happening. PyCharm sees each line of input as being followed by a blank line. The blank lines yield empty tuples. It is harder to say *why* this happens.  But an IDE, by design, provides only an *emulation* of console behaviour. It looks like you've encountered one of the limits of the emulation in Windows.

Comment: To avoid this, you could check if the tuple is empty, and if not, you add it to the list

Comment: @DominikLovetinsky, my loop iters should not be enough for all inputs.

Comment: @BoarGules, But the Windows pycharm works ideally, Ubuntu Pycharm works with issues.

Comment: Sorry, I clearly got that back to front. The comment still applies, though. You might want to report this as a bug to Jetbrains. I'd guess it's something to do with Posix/ Windows end-of-line differences.

Answer (score 2):

Friends, I think, I found the answer. It is the issue related to Pycharm environment. Try enabling "Terminal Emulation".

Open the run configurations and toggle this checkbox:

[image]

Comment: Ticket in PyCharm's issue tracker https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-54238/STDIN-is-lost-for-a-second-input-call