# ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: when give 2 values in different lines

Tags: python, valueerror

I wrote this in PyCharm 2022.1.1:

```
a = int(input())
b = int(input())
print(a)
print(b)
```

I input 7 press Enter and input 10 and press Enter - no extra spaces.

But error was happend (ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''). The error was happened exactly in second line.

I save it into the file and run from command line - work perfectly.

What am I doing wrong?
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XLOSX.png)

Comment: It looks like there is known issue with pycharm. check e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/72255982/4046632

Comment: ticket on pycharm support https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-54238/STDIN-is-lost-for-a-second-input-call

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["""input().split() in loop""" issues in Pycharm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72255982/input-split-in-loop-issues-in-pycharm)

Comment: Yes, I think is same problem. PyCharm lost second input. Thanks.

Comment: PyCharm already fix this issue in version 2022.1.2 Build #PC-221.5787.24, built on May 31, 2022